# SwiftUI Search Core Data With Relationships

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, core-data

I have a SwiftUI app with SwiftUI life cycle and am persisting data in Core Data.
I am using Xcode 14.0.1 and iOS 16 to create a NavigationSplitView architecture.
This all works fine. I have added .searchable to the main list and am able to search
the entity string fields in the entity but I want to include string fields in
the relationship entities and have not been able to do so.

Let's say I have an entity Trip, with name, description and comment attributes - all
Strings. I create a searchResults var and use the result in the list. This works for
the fields discussed.

```
var searchResults: [Trip] {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        return Array(tripsFetched)
    } else {
        return Array(tripsFetched).filter {
            $0.wrappedTripName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            ||
            $0.wrappedTripDescription.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            ||
            $0.wrappedComment.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }//filter
    }//if else
}//var search results
```

Now let's say I have a one to many relationship between Trip and an entity Site and say
Site has string attributes for siteName and siteDescription. I have not been able to
add an iteration over the NSSet of Site objects to look for the searchText. I've made
many attempts including the following but nothing has worked.

```
||
$0.sites?.allObjects(where: $0.wrappedSiteName.contains(searchText.lowercased()))
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to return `true`, if any `Site` has a `wrappedSiteName` that contains `searchText`, correct?

Comment: No. I want to return an array of type Trip for any Trip records with any string field included in the filter which contains the searchText. The code works for the attributes of Trip, but I want to include those Trip records where any of the records in the set of related Site types contain the searchText if the Site attribute is included in the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searching we use the nsPredicate property on the fetch request.

You'll need an or predicate using the contains keyword for the text and equals with either the object or it's id for the relation, but this page shows all the different ways it can be configured:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate

There is a SwiftUI example on this page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest/configuration

```
.onChange(of: query) { value in
    quakes.nsPredicate = query.isEmpty
        ? nil
        : NSPredicate(format: "place CONTAINS %@", value)
}
```

Comment: malhal - Yes, I have used dynamic predicate searches in fetch requests, but I still  don't see how to do that with a Core Data one-to-many relationship. Again, say I have one Trip with an unknown number of Sites in an NSSet. I can easily search any attribute of Trip, but I have not been able to search through the attributes of the NSSet of Sites that are related to that Trip. Maybe you are correct that I need to use a compound predicate search of ALL Sites in Core Data with a where clause that matches the Trip and add that to the Trip predicate search. I'll give that a try.

Comment: See predicates for relationships here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789

Answer (score 0):

For others - malhal is correct. You can create a compound predicate to search the
one-to-many relationships. The important part is the syntax referenced in his links
that uses the ANY keyword. This is an example:

```
func cdSearchQuery(searchText: String) {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Trip.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tripName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    
    let predicateTrip = NSPredicate(format: "tripName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || tripDescription CONTAINS[cd] %@ || tripComment CONTAINS[cd] %@ || tripCompanions CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText)
    
    //for the to-many attributes, use the ANY keyword
    let predicateSite = NSPredicate(format: "ANY sites.siteName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || sites.siteDescription CONTAINS[cd] %@ || sites.siteLocation CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText, searchText, searchText )
    
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateTrip, predicateSite])
    
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        
        //for testing - remove and send results to a Published array
        if let tripArray = Array(results) as? [Trip] {
            for t in tripArray {
                print("included  is \(String(describing: t.tripName))")
            }
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error retrieving compound predicate")
    }

}//cd search
```